# How to count and group items on a line in the Fallout 4 Contraptions DLC?

Tags: fallout-4

I have been trying to set up a line with two ammunition factories. I'm using 3 hoppers to drop 1 fertilizer, 1 lead, and another lead on a single conveyor to make 10mm rounds. I've been googling and searching YouTube but I can't seem to find any answers or ideas for this.

I want to split the single conveyor into two lines to feed two ammunition plants. I tried the laser switches immediately following the split in the line, both connected to an xor gate with the xor output connected to the conveyor belt diverter. This works alright to split single items fairly evenly between the two lines.

I want the line to be able to make any type of ammo requiring any number of ingredients. So I figured I'd try the regular tripwire with an interval counter. This seems to count items correctly, however when the counter fires it isn't a toggle, so the diverter only moves half way before power to it shuts back off.  I tried connecting the counter to a delayed-off switch hoping it would magically supply power to the diverter for a few seconds. This is not the case.

What combination of logic gates would allow me to set a counter and send groups of components to one factory and then toggle to the other factory?

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a hassle. This is why I just buy ammo.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm not excessively late to answer this for you. I got a couple of options:

1. Square wave generator speaker thing:

   I think that if you use one of the square wave generators hooked to one or two counters (you can set the count limit of the counters in a computer) set up to maybe binary (1 & 2 would replace 0 & 1) you could pull it off
2. Belt trip laser

Same thing with the counters, but hooked to a couple of trip lasers to control the timing to your liking.

3. Contraptions DLC

You could set up some kind of clock with the rails and object launchers in a way that they trip the pulse stitches while rolling down.

Don't let anyone hinder your creativity man. I just picked up the game again to build a ammunition crafting facility with multiple plants building, each making different ammo; and I'm over 16 hours of just making it play well together. If you're still playing I recommend you come back to it.